# SQL UPDATE SET SELECT slow

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a SQL UPDATE, but runtime is too long. Record count more than 400000.

```
UPDATE items i 
SET i.itemId = (SELECT o.id FROM itemOri o WHERE i.barcode = o.barcode);
```

Comment: Do you have indexes on the `barcode` columns in both tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have indexes on the `barcode` columns in both tables. Then use a `JOIN` instead of a subquery:

```
UPDATE items i
JOIN itemOri o ON i.barcode = o.barcode
SET i.itemId = o.id
```